# How to avoid creating the duplicate dialog boxes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Footer Page

```
   Link 1 , Link 2  , Link 3
```

Any of these links clicked will open a dialog box  with  data content and footer file.
So ,Dialog will look like:

```
       Data 
       Link 1 , Link 2 , Link 3
```

And when I click on one of the link from Dialog it opens another dialog ,So this logic is going in to a infinite loop.

Is there a way to avoid the duplication of this dialog boxes ?

Open Function:

```
$(function() {

    $('#dialog').dialog('close');   
    // Trying it here but not sure if this is the right place  to do 
   // I want to close all dialog boxes before opening one 

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal:true,
        height:600,
        width:600,
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of:window,
        resizable:false,
        closeOnEscape:false,
        open:function (event, ui) {
                 $('#dialog').load('/contact.jsp');
        }
    });

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog("option", "title", url);
});
```

Still thinking about if I am placing  .close in the right place to begin with ?

Comment: Close them before you open a new one?

Comment: $('#dialog').dialog('close');   is what  I tried but none of my browser FF, Safari , IF , Chrome is detecting  it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a function that's creating this stuff dynamically, thus the loop. 
If so, a solution to avoid duplication is give the Dialog box a class name unique to itself and prior to any creation, use a jquery call to delete any element with that class name.

Here's more info on [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Remove will remove it from the DOM  object , I think close will be the better option than a remove

Comment: Depends. If this is going to extraneous code that's just junking up the app, a close won't delete it like a remove will. (As you stated, a remove will literally remove it.) If the code is actually useful and not just duplication, then a close hypothetically would be fine. Considering the close isn't working, however, I'd suggest just /trying/ a remove, and letting us know how it goes. :)

Comment: - that or try .pluginName('destroy'). Another thing to check is that you're not using dialog('open') incorrectly http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Comment: Well I updated the open function in my code , I hope , I went through the different specs I believe  .close will be the right  option for me  to make it easy but may be I am keeping it at all wrong places

Comment: thanks for updated code above- makes it easier to figure out your problem. Add the close calls or describe those more?

Comment: try calling the open as a function call inside of the close? should look something like $('#dialog').dialog('close', function(){..code here..});

Comment: -- also shouldn't these be associated with button clicks??? Look to this reference if you're not sure what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/T4gz3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15472/discussion-between-kapilp-and-jos)

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the footer file when loading a dialog.

Comment: Well its a part of requirement , so I had to .. otherwise it would have been not a problem

Comment: Is there more to the footer than just the links?  If so, make the visibility of the links optional.  When rendering your main page, have your footer show the links.  When rendering the dialog, hide the links.  Sorry for being vague but you haven't really included much information about your actual code.

Comment: Well Yes , I agree I thought it was more of logical problem than that of code or using right APIS .So kept it on very abstract level.                                     Reason I had to include the footer again is that when I display the dialog box , its covering the current footer content.

Comment: Maybe you should use some other UI element, like tabs? See http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Add a GET parameter to the pages called through your links like `mypage.php?dialog=true`

and in your footer, check if this parameter is present before displaying the links :

```
<?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['dialog'])) : ?>
HTML code to display your link <a href="mypage.php?dialog=true">link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```